# Не отображаются корректно (квадраты) иконки font awesome (v5)

Tags: шрифты, fontawesome

Не отображаются корректно иконки font awesome (v5). Отображаются вместо иконок квадраты. Для подключения шрифта использую данный код:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем оказалось все дело в том, что я подключал файл: `fontawesome.min.css`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Так подключался шрифт `v4`,а в `v5` нужно подключать вот этот файл: `all.min.css`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/all.min.css">
```

После того как я заменил файлы, у меня пропали квадраты.